# My game is running via the Intel integrated GPU instead of my Nvidia GTX 1050

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics, intel-core-i7

Important notes:

- I have a Dell XPS 15 9560
- Processor is Intel core i7-7700 HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
- I have 32.0 GB of RAM
- My Windows 10 is updated.
- I have a GTX 1050
- I have Nvidia geforce
- My Nvidia driver (385.54) is updated and is optimized for performance.
- I tried reinstalling my graphics driver but every time I tried, I got a popup saying "Driver download failed".
- I set my game to the absolute LOWEST graphics.

So for the past few weeks, *League of Legends* has been consistently dropping to a whopping 5-10 frames per second, making it almost unplayable. I opened my task manager and noticed that the Intel integrated GPU was running at 100% while my Nvidia GPU was sitting at a 10-20%. I went into the processes tab of the control panel and it showed that indeed, League was using the intel graphics.

So I went into the Nvidia control panel, went into "Manage 3D Settings" -> Global Settings, and set the "Preferred graphics processor" to "High-performance Nvidia processor".

I re-ran league and sure enough, it still was at 10 FPS. Again, I checked the task manager and League was still running my intel graphics card. Why is this happening?

Comment: Extreme solution is to uninstall your Intel drivers which should force the user of Nvidia device.  However, I would make an appropriate backup, before you try that solution

Comment: I would recommend simply reinstalling the Nvidia drivers. Yes, you say that it states, “Driver download failed.” but what about if you went directly to Nvidia’s site and downloaded the drivers that way.

Comment: If Bios you can disable the integrated GPU. Very low advantage to run them both when a GTX 1050 is present.

Comment: Did you find a solution?